# Make PDF background transparent in Adobe Acrobat Pro XI

Tags: pdf, transparency, adobe-acrobat

I have a vector graphic in PDF with a white background: how can I make the background transparent? I have to import it into some Illustrator document whose background isn't white, so I need the PDF background to be transparent.

[image]

When using the "Edit Text & Images" tool:

[image]

I use Adobe Acrobat Pro XI with Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate.

Comment: Something that simple would be better to rebuild. If it's natively vector you can edit the object and remove the background.

Comment: @Aibrean Thanks, it's natively vectorial I believe, but how to remove the background?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's vector:

- Choose Tools > Content > Edit Object tool.
- Select the object, right-click the selection, and choose Edit Object
- Starts the image editor or object editor you specify in the TouchUp preferences. Edit Image is available when a vector image is selected; Edit Object is available when a bitmap image is selected. Selecting these options removes tags from the PDF, potentially changing how the PDF reflows and affecting accessibility. For example, changing the location of an object affects the order in which that object (or its alternate text) is read by a screen reader.

Then you can remove the background in the program and then save.

However, if you're going to use Illustrator anyway, just open the PDF in Illustrator and it will allow you to edit all vector elements.

---

To select Edit Object:

[image]